# Hive and selecting non matching records

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

I have two table like table A , B  , i need to select non matching records of A with B ( that is A minus B ) .
A is having multiple columns and B is single column( ID) .

I have tried like below but it is taking too much time

```
Select * from A where A.ID <> ( select B.ID from B).
```

And also I have tried

```
Select * from A left outer join on B where A.ID = B.ID AND B.ID IS NULL
```

It's showing me wrong result

Please help me to identify solution to this .

Thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use where clause to filter.

```
 Select * from A left outer join  B on A.ID = B.ID where B.ID IS NULL
```